# getBeaconParsers().add throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, android, altbeacon

I get `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` and the app crashes on following line:

```
this.beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
```

This is part of the stack trace:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
            at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:928)
            at com.cc.office.BeaconMonitoring.BeaconMonitoringCoordinator.detectBeaconsUsingMonitorNotifier(BeaconMonitoringCoordinator.java:75)
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
this.beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
```

was being called after

```
beaconManager.bind(this);
```

The issue was fixed by calling the add function before bind.

Comment: @BlueTrin did you solve the problem im facing same issue.

Comment: Just do what he said, call the add function before the bind.